# On edit of my form It is throwing error

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-3

It might be a silly mistake but taking me ages to solve this issue.

I have existing table called users and I added new column call Approve (bit).
And on my form Edit I am trying to provide check box to approve User for authorisation.

Below is my form:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#"    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<EmsAdmin.Models.User>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="EmsAdmin.Models" %>
 <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
// Focus on the first input box for the site
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#UserId').focus();
});

//]]>
</script>

< %= Html.ValidationSummary("Edit was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try
         again.") %>
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
 {%>

 <%= Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>

 <p>
<%= Html.LabelFor(e=>e.Id,"Id:") %>
<%: Model.Id %>

</p>
<p>

<%= Html.LabelFor(e=>e.PersonId,"Person:") %>
  <%= Html.DropDownListFor(e =>
  e.PersonId, (SelectList)ViewData["allPersons"], "Select
 a person", new { @style = "width: 255px;" })%>
 <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(e=>e.Person,"") %>
 </p>

 <p>
<%= Html.LabelFor(e=>e.Email,"Email:") %>
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.Email, new { @style = "width:250px;" })%>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(e=>e.Email,"") %>
 </p>

<%= Html.LabelFor(e=>e.Approve,"Aprrove User:") %>
<%= Html.CheckBoxFor(e=>e.Approve) %><span>&nbsp;Switch this on if you want to
    display whitespace in the widget rather than out of stock logos</span>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(e=>e.Approve,"") %>
```

I am getting below error :

```
Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Source Error: 


Line 29: </p>
Line 30:     <%= Html.LabelFor(e=>e.Approve,"Aprrove User:") %>
Line 31:     <%= Html.CheckBoxFor(e=>(bool) e.Approve) %><span>&nbsp;Switch this on if you want to
Line 32:         display whitespace in the widget rather than out of stock logos</span>
Line 33:     <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(e=>e.Approve,"") %>

Source File: d:\Dev2010\ems1\Project1\EmsAdmin\Views\ReportUserVerification\UserForm.ascx    Line: 31 

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.]
   System.Web.Mvc.ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(Expression`1 expression, ViewDataDictionary`1 viewData) +513485
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.CheckBoxFor(HtmlHelper`1 htmlHelper, Expression`1 expression, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes) +71
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.CheckBoxFor(HtmlHelper`1 htmlHelper, Expression`1 expression) +54
   ASP.views_reportuserverification_userform_ascx.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in d:\Dev2010\ems1\Project1\EmsAdmin\Views\ReportUserVerification\UserForm.ascx:31
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +268
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +8
   System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +10
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +57
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +128
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +8
   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +41
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +57
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1386
```

My user class:

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

 namespace EmsAdmin.Models
  {
/// <summary>
/// Extends the class created by Linq, so that we can have more control over our linq objects.
/// </summary>
[MetadataType(typeof(UserValidation))]
public partial class User
{
    /// <summary>
    ///  A collection of the Interaction Records for this report
    /// </summary>
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// A collection for displaying brands for the user
    /// </summary>
    public List<Manufacturer> Manufacturers { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Override the to string so that we can use in the delete method to capture details of this record before it is deleted
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("User: Id = {0}, PersonId = {1}, Name = {2}, Email = {3}, Guid = {4}, CreatedAt = {5}, Salt = {6}, Avatar = {7}, Password = {8}, LastLoggedIn = {9}, LoggedInFrom = {10},Approve = {11}", Id, PersonId, Name, Email, Guid, CreatedAt, Salt, Avatar, Password, LastLoggedIn, LoggedInFrom,Approve);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// User Validation
/// </summary>
public class UserValidation
{
    /// <summary>
    /// PersonId
    /// </summary>
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "PersonId is required")]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "PersonId must be valid")]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Name
    /// </summary>
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is a required field")]
    [StringLength(128, ErrorMessage = "Name maximum length is 128", MinimumLength = 1)]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Email
    /// </summary>
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is a required field")]
    [StringLength(128, ErrorMessage = "Email maximum length is 128", MinimumLength = 1)]
    public String Email { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Guid
    /// </summary>
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Guid is a required field")]
    [StringLength(32, ErrorMessage = "Guid maximum length is 32", MinimumLength = 1)]
    public String Guid { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// CreatedAt
    /// </summary>
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "CreatedAt is a required field")]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Salt
    /// </summary>
    [StringLength(9, ErrorMessage = "Salt maximum length is 9")]
    public String Salt { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Avatar
    /// </summary>
    [StringLength(128, ErrorMessage = "Avatar maximum length is 128")]
    public String Avatar { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Password
    /// </summary>
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is a required field")]
    [StringLength(512, ErrorMessage = "Password maximum length is 512", MinimumLength = 1)]
    public String Password { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// LoggedInFrom
    /// </summary>
    [StringLength(25, ErrorMessage = "LoggedInFrom maximum length is 25")]
    public String LoggedInFrom { get; set; }

}
}
```

Comment: Isn't it what it says? "_Templates can be used only with field access, property access..._". Your `Approve()` function is a **function** then it can't be used as expression for `CheckBoxFor` (because it can read a value but it's not possible to write it). It must be a **property** (or a field), change it to that. If `Approve` is a property then just remove `()` and it'll work.

Comment: Try changing `Html.CheckBoxFor(e=>e.Approve()` to `Html.CheckBoxFor(e=>e.Approve`

Comment: @AndreCalil Sorry I think that is an typo error I am getting same error For e => e.Approve

Comment: @62071072 Could you add you `user` class to the question, please?

Comment: @62071072, can you post declaration of the model that view is typed with? Specifically, how is `Approve` member declared?

Comment: @AndreCalil Added my user class

Comment: @62071072 I can't find the `Approve` property. Maybe you added the column to the table but forgot to update your model.

Comment: @AndreCalil public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("User: Id = {0}, PersonId = {1}, Name = {2}, Email = {3}, Guid = {4}, CreatedAt = {5}, Salt = {6}, Avatar = {7}, Password = {8}, LastLoggedIn = {9}, LoggedInFrom = {10},Approve = {11}", Id, PersonId, Name, Email, Guid, CreatedAt, Salt, Avatar, Password, LastLoggedIn, LoggedInFrom,Approve);
    }

Comment: @62071072 This means nothing, it's just a `ToString` override. You need something like `public bool Approve { get; set; }`

Comment: @AndreCalil I added property in my user class but still getting same error. And Approve will allow nulls does that making any difference? I cant set allownulls to false because I have rows existing.

Comment: @62071072 Allow nulls make no difference, but it also makes no sense. You should give your existing rows a default value (let's say, `update users set approve = 0`) and then change it to not null. About your view, could you verify if your code is calling `e.Approve()` or `e.Approve`?

Comment: @AndreCalil My code has e =>e.Approve and it is saying cannot covert expression type 'System.Nullable<bool>' to return type bool.

Comment: @62071072 Ok, now the error is different! Do as I said before and make it not nullable. That is, a regular `bool`.

Comment: @AndreCalil It worked. Can you make it as an answer I will mark it as Answer. Actually I updated all rows for Approve column then it allowed me to set allow nulls to false and it worked

Comment: @62071072 There you go =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after all our chatting, you had to:

1. Make your column not nullable. This is not required, but it makes no sense to have a null-approved user
2. Update your model to fit your table's new column with a `public bool Approved { get; set;}`
3. Use it on your view with `Html.CheckBoxFor(e=>e.Approve)`